# In PyGTK, how to start thread and continue calling function only when thread terminates

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pygtk, pygobject

After reading many questions about threads and `.join()` function, I still can not find how to adapt the basic [pygobject threads example from documentation](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html), so that it matches my use case:

```
#!/bin/python3

import threading
import time
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, GObject

def app_main():
    win = Gtk.Window(default_height=50, default_width=300)
    win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    def update_progess(i):
        progress.pulse()
        progress.set_text(str(i))
        return False

    def example_target():
        for i in range(50):
            GLib.idle_add(update_progess, i)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def start_actions(self):
        print("do a few thing before thread starts")
        thread = threading.Thread(target=example_target)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        print("do other things after thread finished")

    mainBox = Gtk.Box(spacing=20, orientation="vertical")
    win.add(mainBox)
    btn = Gtk.Button(label="start actions")
    btn.connect("clicked", start_actions)
    mainBox.pack_start(btn, False, False, 0)
    progress = Gtk.ProgressBar(show_text=True)
    mainBox.pack_start(progress, False, False, 0)
    win.show_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_main()
    Gtk.main()
```

How to make this code print `"do other things after thread finished"` only after my thread terminates and without freezing main window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to make it clear, the thread isn't finished after you call its `start` method.

Look at the definition of the code running in the thread:

```
def example_target():
    for i in range(50):
        GLib.idle_add(update_progess, i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

What this does is basically repeat the following 50 times:

- tell GTK to execute `update_progress` at the next time the system is idle (has no events to process).
- sleeps for 0.2 seconds.

You could define a function `after_thread`, and have that scheduled when the thread finishes:

```
def example_target():
    for i in range(50):
        GLib.idle_add(update_progess, i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    # loop is finished, thread will end.
    GLib.idle_add(after_thread)
```

Comment: Thanks! Running `GLib.idle_add(after_thread)` was exactly what I needed.